# Mascarar wp-admin/wp-login com .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Estou tentando mascarar a URL de login do Wordpress.
Por exemplo, eu consegui fazer o básico que é fazer a url ser amigável:

```
^login /wp-login.php [L]
```

Acontece que eu não quero permitir o acesso usando a URL direta com `www.site.com/wp-admin` ou `www.site.com/wp-login` ou `www.site.com/wp-login.php` ou `www.site.com/wp-admin.php`, apenas pela URL amigável.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

**Sim é possível!**

Para isso utilize o plugin `Hide Login+` ele serve justamente para isso, com ele você poderá criar novas URLs como `www.meusite.com/login` e ele bloqueia o acesso as outras URLs como `/wp-login` e `/wp-admin`.

Você encontra o plugin em:

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-login/

Comment: Tentei utilizar hoje esse plugin na versão 3.9.1 do Wordpress e ele não funciona mais. Recomendo o [Lockdown WP Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin). Instalação bem mais prática também.

Comment: Estou utilizando o mesmo e funciona perfeitamente. Acredito que você tenha configurado errado. Pode crer.

Comment: Não sei se foi devido a problemas de permissões, mas consegui apenas fazer o redirecionamento. Porém, coloquei 777 em todo diretório do plugin com recursividade. Não entendi o motivo de não ir, esse outro plugin funcionou normalmente sem nenhuma alteração.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, não sei o que você quer fazer quando o usuário acessar uma destas URLs que você não que que seja acessível. Se você quer um 404, pode fazer assim:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/wp-login\.php$  /path-da-page-404.php
```